# Understanding the definition of a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, definition, splitting-field

The splitting field of a polynomial $p$ with coefficients over a field $K$ is defined as the smallest field that contains $K$, in which the polynomial can split into linear factors.

I just want to see if I've understood the definition correctly. Does the splitting field depend not only on the polynomial but also on the field $K$ that we choose?
In the sense that, the splitting field of $p=t^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, but the splitting field of the same polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ would be $\mathbb{R}(i)$?

Comment: That's correct. Note that even writing down a polynomial $p(X)$ requires you to specify what field the coefficients are in. You can think of the splitting field of $p(X)$ over $K$ as "adding all the roots of $p$ to $K$". This certainly depends on $p(X)$.

Comment: Typo, you meant to say $p(t) = t^2+1$. The polynomial $t^2-1$ already splits over any field. Other than that, yes, the splitting field of $t^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ would be $\mathbb{Q}(i)$; over $\mathbb{R}$ it would be $\mathbb{R}(i) \cong \mathbb{C}$; over, say, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, the splitting field would be simply $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, because the polynomial already splits as $t^2+1 = t^2-4 = (t-2)(t+2)$ (taken modulo $5$).

Comment: I fixed the typo, but don't agree with saying this is a correct definition, because talking about “the smallest field” needs an ambient field, specifically an algebraic closure of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

(commenting so you can mark as closed)

Yes this is (except for the typo mentioned in the comments) completely correct.